# Is there a way in TestNG to validate something but not fail the test case at the end (not soft assert)?

Tags: java, testng

I'm using TestNG to run a test and I've been using the Assert.assert statements in Java.

Now there are a few places where I would like to validate whether a function returned true or not. If it didn't then I don't want to fail the test but would rather have it log a message and continue.

In effect, I'm trying something like this:

```
boolean return1 = funct1();
if(bool){
System.out.println("funct1 returned a false. An error occurred which needs to be investigated later but the test will continue for now")
}
```

I could of course do this via the code that I wrote but is there a more elegant method of doing this via TestNG?

How can I make some assertions without failing the test? SoftAssert seems to fail the test at the end when I call assertAll().

Comment: The solution you write seems explicit and elegant. What makes you think it is not elegant?

Comment: @dzieciou he have to write extra Boolean function for each type of validations

Comment: @dzieciou if he want to check greater than , then he have to write a function that checks greater than , if he wants equal then he need a function , for everything he has to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @PHide. Not really. Many functions for checking conditions are already in Java. `if (result > 5) {log.warning("Result to high %s", result );}`. I guess what you mean is good diagnostics messages like "Expected result to be great than 5, actual value was 4", then I agree -- JUnit/TestNG assertions have that reporting builting in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the assert True,

**if you read the documentation of asserttrue:**

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEquals(boolean,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)

you can see that asserttrue throws an error and not an exception. So you have to capture the Throwable.

ANd you can print it to console using **System.err** or use logger as Joao mentioned

```
    try {

        assertTrue(false," Test tfailed");

    } catch (Throwable e) {

        System.err.println(e);
   //     Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
   //   logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.toString());

    }
```

You can also use **softAssert**

```
        SoftAssert a= new SoftAssert();

        a.assertTrue(1==2, "safasfhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
        a.assertTrue(1==2, "sad");
        a.assertTrue(1==2, "test");
        a.assertTrue(1==2, "3");

        try {

            a.assertAll();

        } catch (Throwable  e) {

            System.err.println(e);
        //  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
       //   logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.toString());

        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You can use system.err.println instead of logger

Answer (score 2):

Java has a [logging feature built-in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).

You would probably log a [Severe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#severe(java.lang.String)) or [Warning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#warning(java.lang.String)) message.

Example:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "My message");
```

Naturally, you may want to wrap this logging alongside assertions.

```
class Verifier {
  ...
  public void verifyEquals(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
      try{
        assert obj1.equals(obj2);
      } catch (AssertionError e) {
        logger.log(obj1 + " is not equal to " + obj2);
      }
  } 
}
```

Comment: +1 logger is a good suggestion it makes the error more visible than printing it