# Is there a way to capture Jasmine assertions?

Tags: javascript, protractor, jasmine

Is there a way to capture expect failures in Jasmine?

This doesn't work, the exception is not captured.

```js
try {
  expect(1).toBe(3)
} catch (e) {

}
```

I am looking for something like this TestNG equivalent:

```java
SoftAssert a= new SoftAssert();

a.assertTrue(1==2, "safasfhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
a.assertTrue(1==2, "sad");
a.assertTrue(1==2, "test");
a.assertTrue(1==2, "3");

try {

    a.assertAll();

} catch (Throwable  e) {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.toString());

}
```

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesn't work"*? What was the expected behaviour, and what happens instead?

Comment: It doesn't capture the error , i want to do something like in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/44631/40022

Comment: So that it can report multiple failing assertions, rather than throwing an exception, Jasmine's assertions register a failure for later reporting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i don't want to fail the test i just want to capture the error thrown

Comment: To what end? Maybe you should be looking at a custom matcher or a reporter. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37348183/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe i don't want to fail the test, i just want to get the message thrown by the expect

Comment: Again, to what end? In that TestNG you get to see the output from multiple assertions, but *that already happens* in Jasmine. Please provide the *context*, what's the *problem* you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe in testng it won't fail the test if i catch the throwable, in jasmine it works like assetALL without a try catch

Comment: Yes, that's how it's designed to work. The alternative is "I want the test to pass even though the expectations failed" and doesn't really make sense; in that case maybe you shouldn't be using expectations (in this case just `if (1 !== 3) { console.log("Maths works") }`). Again, please provide the *context* behind this request; do a five whys and give the last one rather than the first.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are seeing it from a simple validation point , i want to capture exceptions that jasmine already has. Don't wnat to reinvent the wheel to write all the exceptions again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a string:

```js
assertExpectation("expect(1).toBe(3)");
```

why not pass a callback, shadowing the global `expect` with the `env`'s:

```js
assertExpectation(function (expect) {
  expect(1).toBe(3);
};
```

This means you can have IDE support on the JS code, rather than at runtime when the `eval` fails, and allows you to have multiple soft expectations (and other code) in one callback. You could implement this like:

```js
function assertExpectation(callback) {
  const env = new jasmine.Env();
  const spec = env.it("", async function () {
    await callback(env.expect);
  });
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    spec.resultCallback = function (result) {
      const messages = result.failedExpectations.map(function (e) {
        return e.message;
      });
      resolve(messages);
    }
    env.execute();
  });
}
```

Note:

1. The `env.describe` was redundant for a single spec;
2. `spec.result` seemed to be populated asynchronously in my testing (using Jasmine 3.5.0), so I've added handling for async code throughout;
3. It now handles multiple messages, rather than just the first; and
4. Your code is a good example of how *not* to use comments, they're either redundant repetition of what the code itself does (e.g. `create a variable spec`) or out of date with the actual implementation (`...along with the stack`).

Given the following in a discovered test file with the above implementation:

```js
it("works how I want", async () => {
  const messages = await assertExpectation(function (expect) {
    expect(1).toBe(3);
  });
  console.log(messages);
  expect(1).toBe(1);
});
```

I get the output

```
$ npm t

> soft-expect@1.0.0 test path/to/soft-expect
> jasmine

Randomized with seed 82972
Started
[ 'Expected 1 to be 3.' ]
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.011 seconds
Randomized with seed 82972 (jasmine --random=true --seed=82972)
```

Comment: Wow that's smart thinking, thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

**Found a workaround for the above issue:**

Here I created a separate Jasmine object and calls the expect inside the new Jasmine object and retrieves the error message.

**Now I can just pass the Jasmine expectation to assertExpectation as a string and get the message:**

```
 assertExpectation=function (expression) {

  //create a variable spec
  let spec;
  //create a jasmine object
  let env = new jasmine.Env()
  //create describe and spec
  env.describe('desc', function () {
    //assign the spec to the spec variable
    spec = env.it('spec', function (done) {
      //`${env.expect(12).toBe(2)}`
      eval("env." + expression)
    })
  })
  // execute the spec
  env.execute()
  //access the spec and print out the message as error along with the stack to know where exactly this error thrown
  // in our actual spec.
  if (spec.result.failedExpectations[0] !== undefined) {
    return (spec.result.failedExpectations[0].message);
  }
}



describe('Validate expectations', function () {

  it('test', async function () {
    await browser.get("https://www.npmjs.com");    
    console.log(assertExpectation("expect('This sentence ').toContain('nothing')"));    
    await browser.get("https://www.protractortest.org/#/jasmine-upgrade")
  });

});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Wouldn't it be better to pass in the env's expect to a callback, so you write e.g. `softAssertion((expect) => expect(1).toBe(3));`? That way you don't have to eval anything and your expectation can actually be e.g. intellisense'd and syntax checked before runtime. Also you could return an array of all failure messages.

Comment: This looks interesting , could you explain how this work where to provide this . If I use expect outside spec then it throws exception saying expect not used with anyspec

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find a way so that test continues after assertion fails then it is important to know that the jasmine expectations are kind of "soft" by default.

It means that the test  continues to execute even after a failure.

Comment: Thanks Vishal , i don't want to fail the test

Comment: It will not fail the test but the assertion , that's the whole point. :)

Comment: it fails the test at the end ,

Comment: I am not sure , why one would not to fail the assertion as well ... except for the fake testing..!

Comment: This is against the basic principle of testing so it does not make any sense!!

Comment: this was something context related we wanted to have this for some internal use . Thanks for the help ,:)